# JTOpen IFS events

Tags: events, ibm-midrange, jtopen

I want to know if the JTOpen has the ability to listen to changes of the IFS. I want to find a way to listen to changes made by other programs and execute an action, such as send by MQ or write to a file in the IFS. I tried adding listener to the IFSFile object but I didn't see any activity when a program wrote into that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's basically two ways to "listen" for IFS events..

Turning on [security auditing](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=i-using-security-audit-journal) and processing the data out of the audit journal.  The [Change Auditing Value (CHGAUD) command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/chgaud.htm) can be used to set the auditing of IFS directories and/or objects.

Making use of the [Integrated File System Scan on Open Exit Program](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/ifsopenexit.htm).  This API was added to enable anti-virus software to scan IFS objects when used.  But you could write your own exit point program to do something else.

Comment: I'm new to AS400 so please be patient. So by executing the command CHGAUD a log is created and where and how can I read that log.